# Spring MVC 5.2.9.RELEASE + Tomcat 10 + JDK 11

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jdk11

Доброго времени суток.

**Проблема:**
Разрабатывая web приложение на Spring MVC 5.2.9.RELEASE и попытавшись запустить его на Tomcat 10 столкнулся с одной очень не приятной особенностью:

1. Tomcat 10 полностью перешел с пакета javax на jakarta, в то время как Spring MVC 5.2.9.RELEASE по прежнему использует javax.
2. javax был полностью убран из JDK 11.

Из этих двух пунктов вытекает следующее:

1. ни контейнер сервлетов, ни JDK не предоставят Spring MVC нужные ему пакет javax.servlet
2. При попытке включить пакет javax.servelt в файл .warб будут происходить постоянные ClassCastException (например: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Servlet)

При этом хочется пользоваться последней версией Tomcat и JDK не ранее 11.

**Вопрос:**

1. Когда Spring перелезит с javax на jakarta и случится ли это вообще?
2. Возможно ли как-то решить конфликт между jakarta и javax не переходя на более старые версии Tomcat?

Comment: javax вы можете добавить в виде зависимости к проекту (gradle или maven). На mvnrepository посмотрите пакет.

Comment: Добавить то можно и я добавил, но проблема вообще в другом.